# Прогнозирование временных рядов без тренда и с явно выраженной дневной сезонностью

Tags: математика, машинное-обучение, r, статистика, анализ-данных

У меня вопрос по поводу статистического прогнозирования солнечной активности.
Сразу оговорю, что познания в области прогнозирования минимальные.
Допустим, есть временной ряд, в котором явно прослеживается дневная и годовая сезонность, так же есть сезонность, связанная с временами года, вот часть ряда:

[image: Часть ряда]

Отсутствует тренд. Все это из-за того, что значения временного ряда напрямую зависят от инсоляции.
Также можно выявить резкие снижения (красный круг на рисунке выше).
Я хочу прогнозировать данный ряд на 24 часа вперед основываясь только на нем.
Изначально пробовал делать прогноз эталонными методами - метод сезонного постоянства:

[image: Метод сезонного постоянства]

Прогноз хорошо повторяет форму, но смущает гладкость.
Так же пробовал авторегрессию высоких порядков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наглядно результаты улучшились.
Все вариации экспоненциального сглаживания Хольта показывают плохой результать.
ARIMA без сезонов также. ARIMA с выделением сезонностей не выбралась даже за день.
Пробовал prophet от facebook, но он явно не для таких рядов, или я не разобрался.

Можете посоветовать методы или модели, которые будут применимы для данного ряда? Или лучше стоит остановится на эталонных методах и не искать сложные модели?
Вообще, осуществима ли идея статистического прогнозирования рядов, связанных с погодой? Осуществима ли она при наличии только ряда с одним параметром (допустим, инсоляцией) или требуется ввод других предикторов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И с Хольтом (точнее - с Хольтом-Винтерсом, конечно, раз у вас есть сезонность) и с SARIMA надо всегда играться - подбирать параметры, искать  лучшие варианты. 
Кроме того, выбросы надо бы предварительно чистить. 
Непонятно, почему первый колокол у вас более гладкий, чем остальные. 
Далее, надо определиться с мерой, которая будет использоваться для анализа прогноза. Не обязательно среднеквадратичная будет наиболее подходящей. Это я к тому, что "смущает гладкость" -  не ответ, нужно это как-то подкрепить аналитикой.
Еще - я надеюсь кросс-валидацию вы не забыли сделать? 
Ну и авторегрессия порядка 900 -  это как-то загадочно.

Про prophet пока ничего сказать не могу, руки не дошли попробовать в деле.

`Вообще, осуществима ли идея статистического прогнозирования рядов, связанных с погодой?` 
- Смотря чего вы ожидаете. 100% нет. Но более менее адекватного приближения - да. И помните прогноз - это не предсказание, это вероятностный артефакт.

`Осуществима ли она при наличии только ряда с одним параметром (допустим, инсоляцией) или требуется ввод других предикторов?`

Если у вас есть больше предикторов, то конечно лучше попробовать с ними. Еще раз повторю, 100% прогноза **никогда** не будет, вам "на берегу" надо определиться, что считать адекватным прогнозом. А так, задача предсказания солнечной активности по временному ряду - весьма популярна при изучении МL. В сети лежат десятки примеров, посмотрите. Может поможет.

Comment: Выбросы связаны с облачностью, так как это излучение, падающее на поверхность земли.
Под кросс-валидацию сойдет подсовывание моделям других рядов?
Порядок авторегрессии получился таким образом:
 _`model_ar <- ar(ts, aic = TRUE, order.max = 1000)`_.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если выбросы связаны с облачностью, то чистить данные обязательно! Скорее всего предварительно сглаживать тоже не помешает в таком случае. Кросс-валидация - это кросс-валидация. Наберите "кросс валидация временных рядов". "Другие ряды" тут не подойдут. Порядок авторегрессии и скользящего среднего я бы определял предварительно по анализу автокоррелограммы.  Кстати, и необходимость интеграции тоже. С R уже много лет как не работал, ничего советовать не берусь. Если совсем грустно станет - можно попробовать  посмотреть в сторону LSTM нейросети.